# Assetic assets with only dumped files

Tags: symfony, bower, assetic

We have started to use Bower (via SpBower) for managing our js and css libs, before realizing it was not possible to install Bower on our current prod server.

The idea is not to generate files on the prod server, but to dump the prod files on dev environment and upload these dumped files. But even in prod mode, Assetic is looking for the source files and bower registers these vendor files, so Assetic throw this exception

```
(Twig_Error_Syntax(code: 0): An exception has been thrown during the compilation 
of a template (\"There is no \"jquery_js\" asset.\")
```

Where jquery_js is called after Bower registration in this way

```
    {% javascripts output='js/vendor-1.js'
        '@jquery_js'
        '@jquery_ui_js'
        '@chartjs_js'
        '@Chart_StackedBar_js_js' %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
```

Is there a way to tell assetic to ignore the assets (jquery_js, jquery_ui_js...) to only look at the output file (vendor-1.js) ? I could not find anything in Symfony2 cookbook.

---

Below are the Assectic and Sp Bower sections in config.yml

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ProjectBundle ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~

sp_bower:
    assetic:
        nest_dependencies: false
    bundles:
        ProjectBundle:
            asset_dir: ../../public/vendor
            cache:
                id: ~
                directory: ../../public/vendor/cache
```

And in config_dev.yml

```
assetic:
    use_controller: false
```

As well as the content of the bower.json file

```
{
    "name": "ProjectBundle",
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "~2.0",
        "jquery.countdown": "~2.0", 
        "jquery-ui": "~1.11",
        "bootstrap": "~3.0",
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, if you don't want Assetic to create the `output` file from the source files, what exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: Let's assume I have 2 servers, 1 for dev, 1 for prod. What I would like is to generate the output files on the dev server using Assetic and Bower and upload on the prod server only the generated output files (not all the sources already aggregated in the output files).

Comment: Ok, I see ... I understand your problem now. Can you please post an example file that uses the bower filter (e.g to generate `@jquery_js`), and the `assetic` section from your `config.yml`?

Comment: @Ixg thanks for your help. I added the corresponding section from `config.yml` (we are using SpBower) and added the content of the `bower.json` file.

Comment: Have you considered using a build server that runs in prod mode and generates all assets so you just need to copy them? Assetic works differently in dev and prod mode, so you need to generate all assets with the "live" mode. But after generating, you should be able to simply copy them and use them on the live server.

Comment: That's actually what we are doing using `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod` but on the live server it's still asking for all the assets specified in the twig templates even though it won't use it. But I think I found a workaround, I'll write an answer for it, thanks for your help @Ixg

Comment: Ok, sorry I couldn't really help. Thanks for posting your solution!

Comment: No problem, thank you anyway for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a work around, not very nice but that solves our problem.

The idea is to use `sp_bower` only on dev env so to put it only in `config_dev.yml` and manually specifying the named assets on prod env so in `config_prod.yml`.

We don't have to actually put the correct path to the source file since we won't generate the output files on prod (but use uploaded ones), we can even use a fake js file (for example a file named `prodDumpAlert.js`) containing for example an alert explaining what's going on.

So the `config_dev.yml` would look like that :

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

assetic:
    assets:
        jquery_js:
            inputs:
                - '@ProjectBundle/Resources/public/utils/prodDumpAlert.js'
        jquery_ui_js:
            inputs:
                - '@ProjectBundle/Resources/public/utils/prodDumpAlert.js'
        chartjs_js:
            inputs:
                - '@ProjectBundle/Resources/public/utils/prodDumpAlert.js'
...
```